# Using I18N messages in grails cucumber test

Tags: grails, groovy, cucumber, geb

I'm writting cucumber test cases in grails project. I want to access messages that are configured in message.properties file

e.g. I have a property configured in message.properties file as:

```
view.user.page.title = View user
```

I have a cucumber step ViewUserSteps.groovy

```
Given(~'^I looged in into the app$') { ->
  //code related to login
}
When(~'^I click view users tab"$') { ->
   // click user tab logic
}
Then(~'^I see I am on View User page$') { ->
   at ViewUserPage
}
```

And ViewUserPage.groovy is

```
import geb.Page
import grails.util.Holders
class ViewUserPage extends Page{
    static url = "${Holders.config.app.url}/users/view"
    static at = {
       waitFor(30,2) { 
           title == "Edit user"  // this title should be fetched from message.properties file 
       }
    }
}
```

Here in ViewUserPage I should be able to fetch the title that is configured in message.properties. Something like g.message(code:'view.user.page.title') or by some other way so that if I change in message.properties, no need to change test case. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe it's not answer to your question but you shouldn't rely on messages.properties file in your tests. It's better to add some test related informations into your html, for example `<body class="test-edit-user">...</body>` and check existence of `body.test-edit-user`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you please tell me why shouldn't we rely on message externalization? I'm not sure that adding a class to particular element and asserting it, would be a good idea. Here my requirement is to verify page title.

Comment: Everytime someone change/update title, your test will fail. I believe that it make more sense to check that your application logic is correct (right page is shown). Verification of translations should be done by translators, not programmers. Eventually if you really need to check this title, it's better I believe to check `key` that is used for translation purposes, not translation itself. Maybe you could replace behaviour of g.message in test phase to return always `code`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get ask the `messageSource` bean what the text is and then compare that to the result of the request.

This can look like this (with `responseData.errors.username` being the result of the request (i.e. the `When` step):

```
Then(~'^an error message is shown that the user name is already used$') {->
    assert responseData.errors.username.contains (message ('user.username.unique'))
}
```

`message` is a small helper function to get the text of the message:

```
String message (String code) {
    getBean ('messageSource').getMessage (code, null, null)
}
```

We added `message` to the `World` object, so that it is automatically available in steps.